# Accessing HeaderFooter.Range via C# changes document appearance

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm automating Word using C#, and finding that if I access the Range property of a HeaderFooter object, Word will make the Headers and Footers visible, even if there is nothing in them, when the document is later opened with Word.

It would seem that the "normal" behaviour of headers and footers (at least in Word 2007 and 2010) is that if the header or footer has no content, it should hide the header/footer area, including hiding the margin of the header/footer.

What I am seeing is that if I just access the Range property of a HeaderFooter object, without even having to change anything, the accessed header/footer is left visible. It's as if accessing the Range property automatically creates something in the document if it doesn't exist.

I'm only interested in accessing the contents of the header/footer if there is any contents in it, specifically Range.InlineShapes. Is there a way to determine if the header/footer has any contents without accessing Range? HeaderFooter.Exists doesn't seem to help in this context.